# Qt & OpenGL : change the state outside paintGL function

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I created a really simple application with Qt Creator, which contains a QOpenGLWidget and a QPushButton that should change the clear color of the opengl widget at every click.

[image]

This is the "core" code:

```
void OpenGLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    qDebug() << "initializeGL";
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}

void OpenGLWidget::paintGL()
{
    qDebug() << "paintGL";
    // changeClearColor();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void OpenGLWidget::changeClearColor()
{
    GLfloat color[4];
    glGetFloatv(GL_COLOR_CLEAR_VALUE, color);

    qDebug() << "bef:" << color[0] << color[1] << color[2] << color[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (color[i] == 0.0f)
        {
            color[i] = 1.0f;
            color[(i+1)%3] = 0.0f;
            break;
        }
    }
    qDebug() << "aft:" << color[0] << color[1] << color[2] << color[3];

    glClearColor(color[0], color[1], color[2], color[3]);
    update();
}
```

As it is, this code doesn't behave as I would have expected. The color value retrieve with the call to glGetFloatv in changeClearColor, always returns (0, 0, 0, 1) and then the updated color will be (1, 0, 0, 1), i.e. red. But this color is not then rendered.

So I think calls to library functions outside paintGL don't have access to the current state of OpenGL. If you uncomment the changeClearColor call in paintGL, this time changeClearColor makes it work, changing the clear color at each frame and retrieving the correct initial color (1, 1, 0, 1), i.e. yellow, set in initializeGL.

Obviously, I can save the clear color in a "global" variable (eg an attribute of my OpenGLWidget class) and then modify and use that value with changeClearColor and paintGL. But I'd like to understand why from changeClearColor I cannot access and change the current state of OpenGL, as in paintGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure the correct `OpenGL` context is made current prior to making any `OpenGL` API calls.  Assuming `OpenGLWidget` inherits from `QOpenGLWidget` try...

```
void OpenGLWidget::changeClearColor()
{
    GLfloat color[4];

    /*
     * Use the correct OpenGL context.
     */
    makeCurrent();
    glGetFloatv(GL_COLOR_CLEAR_VALUE, color);

    qDebug() << "bef:" << color[0] << color[1] << color[2] << color[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (color[i] == 0.0f)
        {
            color[i] = 1.0f;
            color[(i+1)%3] = 0.0f;
            break;
        }
    }
    qDebug() << "aft:" << color[0] << color[1] << color[2] << color[3];

    glClearColor(color[0], color[1], color[2], color[3]);

    /*
     * Signify we're done with the current OpenGL context.
     */
    doneCurrent();
    update();
}
```